# Generated servlet error: source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release Using Jsp Error

Tags: java, jsp

when i send my table data to jsp page along with the ajax call data sending success. but jsp page i got this error.i don't how to fix error. i attached with error and code below

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

```
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 17 in the jsp file: /sales_add.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class product
  location: class org.apache.jsp.sales_005fadd_jsp

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 17 in the jsp file: /sales_add.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class product
  location: class org.apache.jsp.sales_005fadd_jsp

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 17 in the jsp file: /sales_add.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class product
  location: class org.apache.jsp.sales_005fadd_jsp

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 17 in the jsp file: /sales_add.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class product
  location: class org.apache.jsp.sales_005fadd_jsp
```

**Jsp page**

```
<%  

String jsonData = request.getParameter("data");
 Gson gson = new Gson();    
      product data1 = gson.fromJson(jsonData, product.class);
      String item = data1.getItem();
      int price = data1.getPrice();
      int qty = data1.getQty();
      int total = data1.getTotal();


      product user = new product();
      user.setItem(item);
      user.setItem(price);
      user.setItem(qty);
      user.setItem(total);


      String jsonObj = gson.toJson(user);
      out.print(jsonObj);

%>
```

Comment: For a start do not use JSP for writing java code.  Use servlets.  JSP should be used for displaying HTML and data obtained from servlets.  *source value 1.5 is obsolete* is probably a maven error?  check your pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

This message:

```
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
> source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
```

probably means that your web container has not been configured with the version of Java to generate code for and is assuming Java 5.  Check the web container configuration.

Solution: check the web container documentation.  Or ignore the message.  (It is a warning not an error.)

The other errors are due to a missing import in your JSP.  You are trying to use a class called `product`, but the Java compiler can't find it.

Solution: add an import at the start of the page.  The syntax is

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
```

... and you need use the correct *fully qualified* name for your class.

(It is also possible that you have misspelled the name.  The *stylistically correct* name for the class would be `Product`.)

---

Other comments:

- If your class name is *really* called `product`, fix it.  This is a major style error.  It should be `Product`.
- As @Scary Wombat points out, you should **not** use JSPs for arbitrary Java code.  Either code the logic using JSTL (not practical in this case), implement this using a Servlet, or use Spring Boot / Spring MVC or similar technology.  Putting arbitrary Java code into a JSP has a variety of technical and maintainability problems.

  JSPs should only really be used for rendering results from a Servlet as HTML output.  They should not contain business logic,

Comment: how to upgrade this as Java 8

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) this error displayed

Comment: Look at the server log.  Read the log messages.  Understand the log messages.  Find bug and fix it.